# My backup failed DBCC CHECKDB. Now what?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2019, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

Assume the following:

1. I have a database on a production server. I do not regularly run `DBCC CHECKDB` on it.
2. I regularly take full, dif, and transaction log backups on my database.
3. As is good practice, I regular restore the database on a separate server and run `DBCC CHECKDB` on it. [Like this](https://docs.dbatools.io/Test-DbaLastBackup.html).
4. One day, `DBCC CHECKDB` reports that things are very wrong.
5. There is only one true production server. I'm not doing anything smart to give me high availability.

What corrective steps should be taken in a (thankfully hypothetical) situation such as this? I understand that we should be testing our backups, much as I've described above, but I have heard virtually nothing said about what to do when a test fails.

I appreciate that Stack Exchange does not like hypotheticals, but I am certain that there is a lot of known industry best practice and standards that apply in this situation. Too many sources stress the importance of testing your backups for this to be an unanswerable or opinion-based question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One day, DBCC CHECKDB reports that things are very wrong.

> What corrective steps should be taken in a (thankfully hypothetical) situation such as this?

Depends on what it reports as the failure and how severe it is. The following are all possible outcomes with varying actions to be taken:

1. A [false positive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3173766-fix-dbcc-checkdb-or-checktable-returns-false-positives-for-data-corruption-and-assertion-failures-in-sql-server-2014-or-2016-0f82a452-2342-ad42-6f29-a289070fea1c) failure. Obviously not much to do here.
2. An actual failure that can be [automatically repaired without data loss](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/dbcc-checkdb-repair-rebuild/).
3. An actual failure that can be [automatically repaired with data loss](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5645/sql-server-database-corruption-and-impact-of-running-checkdb-repair-with-allow-data-loss/).
4. An actual failure that needs to be manually repaired (typically by an expert).
5. An actual unrepairable failure and accepting a significant amount of data loss by [restoring a backup far back enough before the data corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/08/getting-the-last-good-dbcc-checkdb-date/).

Answer (score 0):

If I run into this situation I would

1. run DBCC CHECKDB on prod server
2. restore previous backups and run CHECKDB hoping to find valid one